# Cypress: Invalid certificate issue for https website

Tags: cypress

The browser reports that the connection is insecure, so the certificate hasn't loaded correctly. However, then manually opening the website it loads correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to fix Invalid certificate issue, It's result in to launching the wrong URL.

I tried with `"chromeWebSecurity": false` in my `cypree.json`, but no luck.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Question is unclear, is it your website? How/Where is it deployed? Do you own the domain name?

Comment: Probably because the certificate is `Issued by: CypressProxyCA` rather than the _actual_ certificate authority for the HTTPS site. For instance, the actual site's issuer is `Trusted Secure Certificate Authority 5`, whereas when you run Cypress tests, it is `CypressProxyCA`. Sorry, I just came here looking for answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but Cypress docs say that it's expected: `You'll notice Chrome display a warning that the 'SSL certificate does not match'. This is normal and correct.`

`Note, that Cypress allows you to optionally specify CA / client certificate`

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Examples-of-what-Cypress-does-under-the-hood.

So if the fake Cypress certificates are causing issues for you, you can try supplying your own certificates.